# Details about Total Access Communication System (TACS)

Tags: telephone, specifications, mobile, documentation

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I am trying to build a base station for a TACS (Total Access Communication System) phone, but I have not found any detailed document about it. The most I have found is a channel table and frequencies, but I would need all the details about channel negotiation, signalling and protocols.

It seems that any info about this old technology has been buried. I hope there is someone here that knows something more about it.

**Update:**
3GPP has told me they have no documentation since it was a pre-ETSI standard.

Comment: The info about that old technology was being generated prior to the internet, so it's probably not very searchable for directly. Try asking 3GPP nicely where their archives are.

Comment: You've started with the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Access_Communication_System) of course?

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes I have seen the wiki page, but there is no detail about FOCC/FVC and RECC signals

Comment: One big issue is that those frequencies have most probably been reused for other services and you can no longer use them (and you could probably not have used them without a relevant licence before that). Other than just for fun, is there a specific reason you want to use that?

Comment: TACS seems to be somewhat related to AMPS, so maybe you can find documentation on that one? Also, searching for "TACS FOCC" on Google yields quite a number of books and other documents which may be relevant.

Comment: @jcaron It is a research project, evaluating old technology with the present knowledge... Often in old tech you can find really neat stuff that engineers have developed to make it work and can also be used to solve present problems. Regarding AMPS, it has different messages so it is not compatible and on Google I can't find anything (I'm in Italy maybe this is why).

Comment: @AlbertoPerro You can change your language settings in Google, that may help. I'm not sure the content is really relevant, but there are quite a few results from various books from back then.

Comment: There's http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slwu002 , "TCM8030 Analog Baseband Processor User’s Guide", which has some details of AMPS/TACS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that the osmocom community have built such project, covering most of the old mobile standards. The project is opensource and can be found at [Osmocom Analog Webpage](http://osmocom-analog.eversberg.eu/). Documentation for the various network is available as well on this website.